# Adding delay to css menu with Jquery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

First I'd like to start by saying I'm very new to jquery and pretty new to JavaScript as well.

I'm looking to add some `jquery/javascript` to a css menu to create a delay between options to prevent a the options closing before a user gets to select it. I did some research and found this [How to add a delay to CSS Vertical Dropdown Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10792903/how-to-add-a-delay-to-css-vertical-dropdown-menu)

But it seems to do the opposite which delays the opening not the closing of the sub menus.

Here is what I have http://jsfiddle.net/5jd7c/6/

Note that if you try to go directly from set 1 to opt 2 by going diagonally it closes the option and you end up in set 2 instead.

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you've said, I think you want the [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) jQuery plugin. It does exactly what you describe and is very stable.

Much easier than doing it from scratch.

Comment: Thanks for that. That is the functionally I'm trying to get. Now I'm just having a hard time making it actually work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the jQuery plugin hoverIntent that mentioned above.
I created a quick sample for [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5jd7c/8/)

I set the delay only on the work menu item, the timeout is 1 second(1000 ms)
and i added an id for work li, and id for its ui list

hope that help.